# When creating a pip package, how do I exclude directories using Manifest.in?

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools, packaging

I am trying to create a pip package and when I create the package it always includes `__pycache__` subdirectories. I am using MANIFEST.in to specify which file types should be included and that works well.

How do I tell MANIFEST.in to exclude specific folders anywhere in the package?

**Edit:** I am trying to exclude a *directory*, not just a file. There are several options in the manifest to exclude files, such as `global-exclude` or `recursive-exclude`. But there is no `global-exclude-dir` option, which is why I asked here.

My setup.py looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='my_package',
    version='0.0.1',
    install_requires=[
        'importlib-metadata; python_version == "3.8"',
    ],
    include_package_data=True,
    package_dir={"my_package": "contrib"},   # renamed src to contrib 
)
```

The manifest contains this:

```
global-include *.npy *.npz
global-include *.txt
# [+ current exclude-directory test]
```

The `global-include` commands are working as intended. I tried the following to exclude any `__pycache__` directories (thanks @phd for their suggestions):

```
prune __pycache__
prune */__pycache__ 
recursive-exclude */__pycache__ *
```

Comment: I tried to exclude a folder, not just files. It appears there is no option for that in the manifest. The command `prune` for example excludes all files in a directory - but not the directory itself. But maybe the issue lies somewhere else in my setup. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Try `prune */__pycache__` or `recursive-exclude */__pycache__ *`

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. It worked and it helped me understand the underlying issue. My goal was to exclude any __pycache__ folders that a user might have left before contributing (hence directory name "contrib"). These pycache folders were deleted using your suggestion! But afterwards, new folders were created for every __init__.py ! So it LOOKED like it didn't worked even if it did.

Comment: Is there a way to mark phd's last comment as the correct answer? I can't see it.

Comment: Comments? No. Only answers can be marked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
prune __pycache__
```

prunes only top-level `__pycache__`. To prune `__pycache__` anywhere in the directory hierarchy use

```
prune */__pycache__
```

Answer (score 2):

The goal of this post was to include any `__pycache__` directories from the pip package. This is not really possible because each `__init__.py` creates a `__pycache__` directory after the manifest is created.

For anyone looking for an answer on how to exclude folders when building a wheel using MANIFEST.in, both suggestions posted by phd are working:

```
prune */__pycache__ 
recursive-exclude */__pycache__ *
```